# Ajax call to servlet to send form

Tags: jquery, ajax, servlets

Am unable to send form to my servlet, am not sure what am doing wrong, my servlet name is SupportReq,

```
var formdata = new FormData();
           if($scope.files.length>0){
           formdata.append("attachment0",$scope.files[0]);
           }
           formdata.append("description",$scope.rsp.observations);
           formdata.append("title",$scope.rsp.title);
           $scope.rsp.severity = null;
           $scope.rsp.urgency = 'N';
           formdata.append("secerity",$scope.rsp.severity);
           formdata.append("urgency",$scope.rsp.urgency);
           formdata.append("reviewDate",$scope.date);
           formdata.append("subtopic",subtopictest.id);            

           $.ajax({
                url: 'SupportRequest',
                data: $(".formdata").serialize(),
                contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
                processData: false,
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
```

What might be wrong here?

This is my web.xml

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>SupportRequest</servlet-name>
<display-name>SupportRequest</display-name>
<description></description>
<servlet-class>com.request.SupportRequestCreatorServlet</servlet-class>
```

Comment: share some code of servlet (Url Mapping ....)?

Comment: Yes i added a part of my web.xml

Comment: Ok ... take a look at : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects

Answer (score 0):

This line in ajax call :

```
data: $(".formdata").serialize(),
```

Should be :

```
   data:formdata,
```

For more info , check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5976031/747579) .

__

[Useful DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/ZG9re/5648/)

Comment: But it doesnt seem to work cause i get an error: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found